# Ubuntu 12.04 Problem connecting Internet by Mobile Broadband through LG GU220

Tags: 12.04, mobile-broadband, lg

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I use my LG cellphone titled GU220 using Aircel connection. The phone gets connected as an USB device well enough, but the network always fails to connect whenever I try to connect through mobile broadband. I also have Windows 7 which does not fail to connect the network through PC Suite.

I tried it several times even after restarting both phone and Ubuntu but in vain.

Also for 1st two days things worked well and the network was well connected; the problem  started just after those two days - in from the next login.

Comment: have you tried using wvdial?

Answer (score 0):

First call your Aircel customer care and asked following GPRS setting details.

Dial up No. ( may be something like *99# )

APN.

Go to Network settings, Mobile Broadband , choose country, Choose provider, Finish. 
You will be able to see aircel connection in  Mobile broadband section. select it and choose edit from right pane.

Fill dial up no and APN given by aircel customer care. Make sure that you have filled perfect details

Try to Connect internet, You will have success.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this- Connect usb stick first in other os(eg. windows) if you have dual boot and then you can boot Ubuntu. You may be automatically find internet connectivity option. Just connect and enjoy. I am not sure but it may work..

Comment: that's not a solution, he needed solution